# How to search for how much duplicate in mysql and compare it

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

So I want to compare variable `a` and variable `b` based on how much duplicate they have in mysql. And this is my code:

```
query = """ SELECT `do` FROM `foo` """
cursor.execute(query)
result=cursor.fetchall()

a = '0001'
b = '1100'
y = collections.Counter(result)
print(y)
```

And this my output:

```
Counter({('0001',): 2, ('1100',): 1}, ('0000',): 4})
```

The output is counting the duplicate of the entire row. And I want it to just count how much `a` and `b` in mysql.

And I don't actually know what to do after this. I want the code to run 
if `a > b` print `a`. 
if `a < b` print `b`
Output that I want :

```
a = 2 # number of duplicates
b = 1
a # print a because a > b
```

Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
a = ("0001",)  # Set to tuples so you can directly use them as keys
b = ("1100",)

y = Counter({('0001',): 2, ('1100',): 1, ('0000',): 4})

a_count = y.get(a)  # The number of times `("0001",)` occurs
b_count = y.get(b)  # The number of times `("1100",)` occurs

if a_count > b_count:
    print(a)
elif a_count < b_count:
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more sophisticated query to extract the data you need, and reduce the amount of work you need to do in Python.

This query extracts the value of `do`, and the number of rows that contain that value of `do` for the values of `do` specified in the `WHERE` clause.

```
stmt = """SELECT do, COUNT(do)
          FROM foo
          WHERE do IN ('0001', '1100')
          GROUP BY do;"""
cursor.execute(stmt)
result=cursor.fetchall()   # [('0001', 2), ('1100', 1)]

largest = max(result, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(largest[0])
```

Or you could do *all* the work in the database.  This query groups values and their row counts like the previous query, but orders them in descending order of row count, and returns the first row.

```
stmt = """SELECT do, COUNT(do) AS do_count 
          FROM foo 
          WHERE do IN ('0001', '1100') 
          GROUP BY do 
          ORDER BY do_count DESC 
          LIMIT 1;"""
cur.execute(stmt)
result = cursor.fetchone()    # ('0001', 2)
print(result[0])
```

Note both of these methods assume that there will not be two values of `do` with the same row count, as does the code in the question.  If the code were to handle this case, additional sorting criteria would have to be specified in the key function for `max` in the first example, or the `ORDER BY` clause in the second example.